# Add values between special chars using sed

Tags: sed

I want to add respective values between `''` for database, username etc.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => '',
      'username' => '',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => '',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I already tried following, but didn't work.

```
sed -ie 's/'database' => ''/'database' => 'testdb'/g' file
```

Comment: You need to escape special characters, like quotes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this (Using double quotes around your `sed` command:

```
sed -i "s/'database' => ''/'database' => 'testdb'/g" file
```

Or a better regex to handle 0 or more spaces:

```
sed -i "s/'database' *=> *''/'database' => 'testdb'/g" file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed  "/username/ s/''/'blabla'/" inputfile
```

This will search for the string `username` if it is matched then replace `''` with `'blabla` in the inputfile.

You can use `sed -i.bak` option to reflect changes in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case, I have multiple blocks as above within the same file and need to add values only for a specific block.

Comment: But thanks I could use this for another way in a different requirement :)